# Braintree's showing X-FRAME-OPTION error for one of its dependencies

Tags: braintree, x-frame-options, cross-site

I am facing with an error as below while my site tries to invoke the `Braintree` for the user's payment. This started happening earlier this morning and persists till now! (To see the error please click on the image below.)

[image]

#### Question:

Is there anything I can do, or the problems relies on `CardinalCommerce` and the `Braintree`'s shoulders?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

In order to link a PayPal sandbox test account to your Braintree sandbox account, you will need the API credentials for that PayPal sandbox test account. Please follow [these steps](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live) to create a PayPal sandbox test account and update the credentials in your Braintree sandbox.

Comment: PayPal was not the issue, but it got fixed after some time by its' own, guessing your folks were doing something back in those days which got fixed later. but since you work at braintree please help me on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58247198/1198291) question. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, there were 2 errors displayed and the first was a PayPal error. Happy to hear the X-FRAME-OPTION error was resolved. I will answer the other question in that thread.