# How to edit a card in Braintree's dropin in UI?

Tags: braintree

I'm using Braintree for my site's payments and it works well except that when a user has selected a payment card from its chrome's history and he/she mistakenly inputs a wrong `CVV` the Braintree will fail the transaction (when trying to verify) but it saves the credit card and the user cannot edit him/her mistake, and only thing he/she can is to delete the CC using the Braintree's `vault manager` and re-enter again!

#### Question:

How can I make drop-in to edit the selected card when the card's verification fails?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Vault manager does not allow the ability to edit the CVV (or any values) on the cards saved to the Vault. I can certainly pass this along as a future feature request.

This does not sound like the expected behavior if you are verifying prior to Vaulting in production and have CVV rules enabled to reject if the CVV does not match. If you are running into this error in production, please reach out to our [Support team](https://help.braintreepayments.com/) with an example. If this is in sandbox, please ensure you are using a [test CVV](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing#cvv/cid-responses) to trigger the desired response.